# Javascript - how to test a function that updates the document (DOM)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jsdom

I have the following function:

```
var doSomething = function(){
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('insertHere');
    var item = document.createElement('a');
    item.innerHTML = "hello";
    insertHere.appendChild(item);
};
```

As you can see, this adds an item directly to the `document`. I want to test this function and not sure of the best way to do it. I thought about using jsdom, but `doSomething` expects document to be available and the only way I can see how to do this is to pass `document` in as an optional argument...

```
// In my test, create a document using jsdom and pass it to the function.
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var jsdomDocument = jsdom("<html><body><div id='insertHere'></div></body></html>");
doSomething(jsdomDocument );

// Then adjust the function to accept this document.
var doSomething = function(jsdomDocument){
    document = jsdomDocument || document;
    ...
};
```

...or is there a better way to test this function?

Comment: It would separate concerns more and make it easier to test if you took  `insertHere` as an argument. That way you don't have to mock the whole document, only the node stuff will be appended to.

Comment: This still doesn't allow ```document.createElement('a');``` to work because there is no ```document``` present when testing. Also worth mentioning that I am testing via node (so that I can use the jsdom npm package) - is this the best way to test in this scenario?

Comment: That's a valid point. You could take either `document` or just `createElement` as an argument as well. However your solution (taking document as an argument) is absolutely not bad. But if you do that I wouldn't do `jsdomDocument || document` there. Just give it the real `document` when using it in other parts in your code and the `jsdom` one in tests